# How can I do Jest API test for this code?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, unit-testing, mocking, jestjs

I have tried several ways for mocking this unit of my code but still, it doesn't work. I'm using create-react-app and jest for testing.

I have a function in admin **adminSignup.js** for sending data to my server(Node.js and Mongoose) for creating account:

```
/* eslint-disable no-undef */
 function signup(user, cb) {
 return fetch(`signup`, {
  headers: {"Content-Type": "application/json"},
  method: "POST",
  body:JSON.stringify({
    username: user.username,
    email: user.email,
    password: user.password,
    picode: user.pincode,
    building: user.building,
    city: user.city,
    state: user.state
        }),
})
  .then(checkStatus)
  .then(parseJSON)
  .then(cb)
  .catch(err => console.log(err));
}

function checkStatus(response) {
 if (response.status >= 200 && response.status < 300) {
  return response;
}
const error = new Error(`HTTP Error ${response.statusText}`);
error.status = response.statusText;
error.response = response;
console.log(error); // eslint-disable-line no-console
throw error;
}

function parseJSON(response) {
return response.json();
}

const adminSignup = { signup };
export default adminSignup;
```

and I have called this in my component(**RegisterPage.jsx**) :

```
adminSignup.signup( user, response => {
                         this.setState({response: response});
                         console.log(response);
                   });
```

Now I want to write a mock for my signup call(**adminSignup.js**). But just wonder how can I do this?

I have tried **[Jest Fetch Mock](https://github.com/jefflau/jest-fetch-mock#simple-mock-and-assert)** for mock testing(it doesnt need to create mock file) and it's working but I'm not quite sure is it correct or no :

```
describe('testing api', () => {
beforeEach(() => {
  fetch.resetMocks();
});

it('calls signup and returns message to me', () => {
  expect.assertions(1);
  fetch.mockResponseOnce(JSON.stringify('Account Created Successfully,Please Check Your Email For Account Confirmation.' ));

  //assert on the response
  adminSignup.signup({
    "email" : "sample@yahoo.com",
    "password" : "$2a$0yuImLGh1NIoJoRe8VKmoRkLbuH8SU6o2a",
    "username" : "username",
    "pincode" : "1",
    "city" : "Sydney",
    "building" : "1",
    "state" : "NSW"
}).then(res => {
    expect(res).toEqual('Account Created Successfully,Please Check Your Email For Account Confirmation.');
  });

  //assert on the times called and arguments given to fetch
  expect(fetch.mock.calls.length).toEqual(1);
});
});
```

I really like to create a mock file and test with that but reading jest website is not working for me.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found this way(using mock-http-server) for another **POST** request and it works for me:

***userList.js:***

```
async function getUser (id, cb) {

const response =  await fetch(`/getUserById/${id}`, {
  // headers: {"Content-Type": "application/json"},
  method: "POST",
  body:JSON.stringify({
    id : id
        }),
})
   .then(checkStatus)
   .then(parseJSON)
   .then(cb)
   .catch(err => console.log(err));

const user = response.json();
return user;

 function checkStatus(response) {
   if (response.status >= 200 && response.status < 300) {
     return response;
   }
   const error = new Error(`HTTP Error ${response.statusText}`);
   error.status = response.statusText;
   error.response = response;
   console.log(error); // eslint-disable-line no-console
   throw error;
 }

 function parseJSON(response) {
   return response.json();
 }
}
```

***userList.test.js:***

```
import ServerMock from "mock-http-server";
import userLists from '../components/UserList/userLists';

describe('Test with mock-http-server', function() {

// Run an HTTP server on localhost:3000
var server = new ServerMock({ host: "localhost", port: 3000 });

beforeEach(function(done) {
  server.start(done);
});

afterEach(function(done) {
  server.stop(done);
});

it('should do something',  function(done) {
  var id = 4;
    server.on({
      method: 'POST',
      path: `/getUserById/${id}`,
      reply: {
          status:  200,
          headers: { "content-type": "application/json" },
          body:    JSON.stringify({ id: 4 })
      }
  });
  // Now the server mock will handle a GET http://localhost:3000//getUserById/${id}
  // and will reply with 200 `{"id": 4}`
  function cb(data) {
          console.log(data);
          expect(data).toBe({name:'Bob'}); 
          done();
      }
  const response =  userLists.getUser(4, cb);
  console.log(response);


  done();
});
```